# How to convert date format to DD MMM YYYY in date picker using Bootstrap 4 in angular 8

Tags: date, bootstrap-4, datepicker, format, angular8

```
    <div class="col-sm-8">
                <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                <input
                  id="dtpFrom"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Datepicker"
                  placement="top"
                  class="form-control"
                  bsDatepicker
                  [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY',containerClass: 'theme-blue'}"
                  [bsValue]="todayDate"
                  [minDate]="minDate"
                  [maxDate]="maxDate"
                />
              </div>
```

```
    import { BsDatepickerConfig } from'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
    export class CardlessTransactionsComponent implements OnInit {

    datePickerConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
    privatetodayDate: Date = newDate();
    minDate: Date;
    maxDate: Date;
    }

    constructor(privatefb:FormBuilder) {
    this.todayDate = newDate();
    this.minDate = newDate();
    this.maxDate = newDate();
    this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() - 7);
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 0);
```

at the HTML file, I think there is something need to do inside the bsValue while at the ts file, I have no idea where to change to get the output that I want which is to make it display the month's name instead of the month numeric value

Answer (score 0):

You should get today's date through a `formControl` instead of outside it to get this working...

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        <input
          id="dtpFrom"
          placeholder="Datepicker"
          placement="top"
          class="form-control"
          bsDatepicker
          formControlName="dateMDY"
          [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY',containerClass: 'theme-blue'}"
          [bsValue]="todayDate"
          [minDate]="minDate"
          [maxDate]="maxDate"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-taamwv)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, i have already figure it out. (make changes at the TS file)

```
initializeForm () {
this.cardlessForm= this.fb.group ({
dateFrom:new Date(),
dateTo:new Date ()
});
```

}
I just add the 'new Date ()' at the dateFrom and dateTo then i removed the code ( this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 0);